# Convey complex css in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

Functional css make DX a pleasant, but I always wonder how do we convey some thing like

```
.item + item {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

into our template using tailwindcss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write your own [plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants) for this

```js
// tailwind.config.js

const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin( ({ addVariant, e }) => {
        addVariant('item', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
            modifySelectors(
                ({ className }) => {
                    const eClassName = e(`item${separator}${className}`); // escaped class. This is like `item:bg-red-500` basically
                    return `[class^="item"] + .${eClassName}`; // this is your CSS selector
                }
            )
        })
    })
  ],
}
```

I chose this `[class^="item"]` selector (class starts with `item`) as it is allows not to have extra classes in HTML layout but it is up to you which you want to have

Use it as custom Tailwind variant like `item:any-tailwind-class`

```html
<div class="item:mt-5 item:bg-red-500">1 - No `item` above - no CSS applied</div>
<div class="item:mt-5 item:text-yellow-500">2 - There is `item` above - CSS applied</div>
<div class="item:mt-5 item:bg-red-500 item:text-yellow-500">3</div>
<div class="item:mt-5 item:bg-red-500">4</div>
<div class="item:mt-5">5 - Has margin-top</div>
<div class="">6 - Nothing here</div>
<div class="item:bg-red-500">7- No `item` above - no color applied</div>
<div class="item">8 - This class starts with `item` so the next div should have styles</div>
<div class="item:mt-5 item:bg-red-500">9 - There is `item` above - CSS applied</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/eacLpq2SY9)

Comment: Although I would prefer a simpler answer if there are any.
But this seem legit and the plugin work well.